# How to change the UP-Vector of meshes in Python?

Tags: python, mesh, collada, trimesh

this is probably a noob question but I was unable to find anything:

I am importing a 3D Dataset to a robot simulation environment (CoppeliaSim). When I import the objects, all are oriented in the right way, but it seems, that they have different "Up-Vectors". So when I would orient all of them to the neutral orientation (0,0,0), they all would point in different directions. Please see the attached screenshot as an example:

[Example picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rh9h3.png)

Now, I need every object to have the same up-vector, preferably Z-up. How can I achieve this programmatically in python? I tried to rotate the objects with trimesh, but this only changed the resulting default orientation in the scene, not how the mesh is oriented with respect to its own coordinate system... Essentially I would like to "swap" the mesh axes, e.g. switch the X with the Y axis. I am exporting and importing the meshes as DAE currently, but I could also use other formats